# .NET Core Cookie Authentication SignInAsync not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a cookie authentication based core project using the AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies but I can't seem to make the user to authenticate. I have read similar threads but none of the solutions provided seem useful.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CookieAuth(ITwitterCredentials userCreds)
{
    var claims = new[] {
        new Claim("AccessToken" , userCreds.AccessToken),
        new Claim("AccessTokenSecret", userCreds.AccessTokenSecret)
    };

    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "CookieAuthentication"));

    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("CookieAuthentication", principal);

    return Ok();
}
```

and startup.cs configure method

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "CookieAuthentication",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/"),
    AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/"),
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true
});
```

The user does not seem to authenticate as `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` always returns false.

Any idea why this might not be working?

Comment: Show us the rest of your services registration (Twitter setup, etc. -- secrets removed, of course).

Answer (score 21):

as of .net 2.x, if you're using cookie auth, ensure you include the authenticationScheme and specify name and role claim types, the identity and auth properties.

```
//You should specify the 'types' of the claims which acts as 'name' and 'role', furthermore, you should have claims with those types in your claimsIdentity like that
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
        
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, email));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, email));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));

var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    AllowRefresh = true,
    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1),
    IsPersistent = true,
};
        
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(principal),authProperties);

return RedirectToPage("dashboard");
```

Answer (score 7):

Try to clear browser cache and cookies, then retry.

Comment: @joab That works for me also. What would be a logical reason for that? And how can we force it programmatically from server to clear the cache of the browser

Comment: Thanks worked for me. Also try testing in different browser

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was **options.Cookie.SecurePolicy**, our hosted application was not on HTTPS yet.

```
.AddCookie(config =>
        {
            config.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            //options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            config.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
            config.Cookie.Name = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            config.LoginPath = "/Login";
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

As explaned in the previous answers, essentialy you should add `Name` and `Role` claims to your new identity. If your `HttpContext.SignInAsync` method succeeded your `HttpContext` is now depends on cookies and you are authenticated. I just want to add a very important point about placing middleware handlers in `Configure` method  of the `Startup` class.
If you try to get your context filled with identity values, do it **after** your authentication middleware.
[image: middleware]
Otherwise in your middleware you'll get `HttpContext` blank (without identity data).

Comment: I think the name and value claim types are the key missing points

Answer (score 3):

I think your `startup configure` service missing the following lines of code:

```
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens when you try to run with Http, enable SSL should fix your problem, its in the project Debug section.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Decorate the class with `AuthenticationScheme`

Like this:

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class LoginController : PageController<LoginPage>
```

That whas the key for me!
All `HttpContext` properies magically was set correctly.